# Question about the recursion relation for the 1d random walk and Pascal's rule

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, random-walk

Reading "Elements of the Random Walk" written by Joseph Rudnick and George Gaspari, i am confused by the recursion relation they gave on page 13. the book says that For 1d discrete random walk with step length $l$ and equal probability of traveling right and left at any site,
$$C(N{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y) = C(N - 1{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y - l) + C(N - 1{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y + l) \tag{1}$$
with $C(N{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y)$ is equal to the number of walks that start at x and end up
at y.

The book says that the above equation is equivalent to Pascal's rule
$$\frac{{N!}}{{n!(N - n)!}} = \frac{{(N - 1)!}}{{(n - 1)!(N - n)!}} + \frac{{(N - 1)!}}{{n!(N - n - 1)!}}$$

I know that
$$P(N{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y) = \frac{1}{{{2^N}}}\frac{{N!}}{{n!(N - n)!}}{\rm{ = }}\frac{1}{{{2^N}}}C(N{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y)\tag{2}$$
if $y-x=nl$.
The master equation is
$$P(N{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y) = \frac{{\rm{1}}}{{\rm{2}}}P(N - 1{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y - l) + \frac{{\rm{1}}}{{\rm{2}}}P(N - 1{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y + l)\tag{3}$$

where $P(N{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y)$ is the probability of the walk that start at x and end up
at y. The combination of equation 2 and 3 will give equation 1.

What puzzles me is that as
$$C(N - 1{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y + l) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{N - 1}\\
{n + 1}
\end{array}} \right){\rm{ = }}\frac{1}{{{2^{N - 1}}}}\frac{{(N - 1)!}}{{(n + 1)!(N - n - 2)!}}$$

Should equation 1 gives
$$\frac{{N!}}{{n!(N - n)!}} = \frac{{(N - 1)!}}{{(n - 1)!(N - n)!}} + \frac{{(N - 1)!}}{{(n + 1)!(N - n - 2)!}}$$

This seems to be different from the Pascal's rule, so where am i wrong. Thanks for your help!

---

After discussion with @epi163sqrt, I found that my mistake was that I take for granted that $y-x=nl$ for $C(N {\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y )$ as i wrote above. Instead it should be $y-x=(2n-N)l$.

I didn't change the origin post in order to help guys who make similar mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hint:** The right-most term of (1) and the right-most term of Pascal's rule coincide. We therefore have
> \begin{align*}
> C(N-1;x;y+l)=\frac{(N-1)!}{n!(N-n-1)!}\color{blue}{=\binom{N-1}{n}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:* The identity (1) is valid, since we have the situation
\begin{align*}
C(N;x;y)=\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}
\end{align*}
where we consider according to the book $N$-step walks with

- $n$ steps to the right and
- $N-n$ steps to the left

When we now look at the right-most term of
\begin{align*}
C(N;x;y)=C(N-1;x;y-l)+C(N-1;x;y+l)
\end{align*}
with the interpretation of $n$ given above, we see, that since $y+l$ is to the *right* of $y$ we have done all $n$ steps to the right. Since the right-most term represents the number of $N-1$-step walks to $y+l$, we have also done $(N-1)-n$ steps to the left, resulting in
\begin{align*}
\binom{N-1}{n}
\end{align*}
different walks.

Comment: I agree. But from $C(N - 1{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y + l)$ itself, does it means number of ways to select $n+1$ from $N-1$ such that $C(N - 1{\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y + l) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{N - 1}\\
{n + 1}
\end{array}} \right)$

Comment: @FaDA: I've added a comment which might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your patience!  "that since y+l is to the right of y we have done all n steps to the right."    That is exactly what i am confused. In my opinion, $y+l$ should correspond to $n+1$ as $y$ corresponds to $n$

Comment: @FaDA: You're welcome. The right-most term tells us, we have done all $n$ steps to the right and *one step to the left is left* to complete the $N-1$-step walks from $y+l$ to the $N$-step walks to $y$. The other term on the right-hand side tells us we have done all $N-1-n$ steps to the left and one step *to the right is left* to complete the $N-1$-step walks from $y-l$ to $y$.

Comment: Thanks! I understood where was my mistake. I wrongly take $y-x=nl$ for $C(N {\rm{ }};{\rm{ }}x,{\rm{ }}y )$ as i wrote in the post. Instead it should be $y-x=(2n-N)l$

Comment: @FaDA: Ok, I see. You're welcome! :-)